# Why this Code is Giving ERROR

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, toad

I am unable to use simple SELECT statement to initialize a variable.

```
DECLARE
A VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
A := (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM FIMS_OWNER.EMPLOYEE_T WHERE WWID = 'NA734');
END;
/
```

ERROR:

```
[Error] Execution (4: 11): ORA-06550: line 4, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternat
ORA-06550: line 4, column 76:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

   * & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and
   or group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect || multiset
```

And if it's not possible, what's the alternative for the same.

**PS**: I am using such query to set the variable(and later use it) with my cursor which takes the `WWID` dynamically and then changes the value accordingly.

**Image**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzSDk.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be

```
DECLARE
A VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
SELECT FIRST_NAME INTO A FROM FIMS_OWNER.EMPLOYEE_T WHERE WWID = 'NA734';
END;
```

You should use the INTO clause to select a value into a variable

Answer (score 2):

Because in Oracle you cannot assign a query to a variable. However, you can query into a variable, as in ...

```
DECLARE
    A VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT FIRST_NAME
    INTO A
    FROM FIMS_OWNER.EMPLOYEE_T
    WHERE WWID = 'NA734';
END;
/
```